# Linux mint not installing from USB

Tags: usb, usb-drive, live-usb

I created a Linux Mint Drive on a USB and have successfully installed it on one of my laptops (using this [guide](https://linuxhint.com/installing_linux_mint_20_from_usb/)). When I try to install it on another laptop, the installation proceeds as normal (no errors) but when I restart and remove the USB, it seems as if the installation didn't happen and I get the following message:

[image: Message when I try to reboot after removing the USB]

Is Linux installing properly to the laptop? Or is there an error with the USB?

Answer (score 1):

I would write this in a comment but as a new contributor I can' do that.

PXE-M0F error indicates your system is trying to boot from a network drive.

First I would try to check the boot order in the bios. If hardware is been detected then select the disk as a first boot priority.

> In computing, the Preboot eXecution Environment, PXE (most often pronounced as /ˈpɪksiː/ pixie, often called PXE Boot/pixie boot.) specification describes a standardized client–server environment that boots a software assembly, retrieved from a network, on PXE-enabled clients.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preboot_Execution_Environment

Comment: yep, I'd say this is correct. Change the boot order (USB second) in your bios